# What is the proper way of creating an entity in libgdx ashley ecs framework pooled engine?

Tags: java, libgdx, entity-component-system

```
// GameWorld
PooledEngine engine = new PooledEngine();

// Gun class
class Gun {
   publc Gun(Entity entity) {
        createComponents();
        addComponents();
   }

   public Entity getEntity();
}

// Option 1
Gun gun = new Gun(engine.createEntity());
engine.addEntity(gun.getEntity());

// Option 2 or a simple method inside EntityFactory class
public Entity createGun() {
    Entity gun = engine.createEntity();
    // components creation here
    ..
    engine.addEntity(gun);
    return gun;
}
```

**Question** which one is the better way of creating an `Entity` made from the `PooledEngine`?

- option 1, I create a new `class` called `Gun` then handle the creation of components there.
- option 2, Inside the `EntityFactory` `class` add new method called `createGun()`

  ```
  class EntityFactory {
   // constructor 
   public void build() {
      // Option 1
      Gun gun = new Gun(engine.createEntity());
      // where I can call gun.fire(), gun.reload(), gun.dispose, and so on..
      engine.addEntity(gun.getEntity());


      // Option 2
      Entity gun = createGun();
      engine.addEntity(gun);
   }

   public Entity createGun() {
      Entity gun = engine.createEntity();
      // components creation here
      ...
      engine.addEntity(gun);
      return gun;
   }
  }

  EntityFactory factory = new EntityFactory(world, engine);
  factory.build();
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer the second method via an `EntityFactory`.

Explanation:

- Whereas the EntityFactory is a clean representation of the common factory pattern, you Gun looks like a [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) but with just one method for creating an `Entity`. So it makes no sense to use a new instance for every `Entity` creation as you store no building state in the instance.
- Your `Gun` class is just a wrapper for an `Entity`. But if you get an `Entity`from `engine.getEntitiesFor(Family...` you cannot get it's `Gun` wrapper. So you cannot really use it for anything in your engine's systems.
- If your `EntityFactory` gets too complex and long, I'd recommend to split it into a `GunFactory`, `BananaFactory` and so on.

Comment: what If I added states, methods on my gun class? do you think its better now to create a new wrapper?

Comment: I will mark this as answer, I think I'm gonna use builder pattern. Thanks! it helps me a lot!